# Input for numbers only and add a max number of letters

Tags: html, css, input, styling

i have to make input field only for numbers where the maxsize of letters is 3. 
How can i do this?

This code don't work:

```
<input type="number" class="input first" id="first"  placeholder="000" maxlength="3">
```

The maxlength only work if the type of my input field is "text". Is there an other solution for this.

Additionally: Is there a solution that i disable the browser icons for number fields? The reason why i use the type number is for a better usability with small devices. But at the normal screen, the automatic icons are very ugly.

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use the `max` property

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vrytfm4x/)

```
<input type="number" class="input first" id="first"  placeholder="000" max="999">
```

EDIT - (thanks to 'moss')

Support:
ie10+(without spinner buttons)
iOS & android browsers don't show spinner buttons or us min/max attrs, 
Opera Mini - no support on opera mini. 
Firefox is past 3 versions.

Good support in Chrome, Safari, and Opera [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)

Comment: Support: ie10+(without spinner buttons), iOS & android browsers don't show spinner buttons or use min/max attrs, no support on opera mini. Firefox is past 3 versions. Good support in Chrome, Safari, and Opera.

Comment: Worked in my Chrome.It will show manually entered numbers greater that 999 but will not accept them.

Comment: *with  of course :)    Ok thats true. But i want only to see two digits. Is there no solution without js?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do several things:

- With JavaScript you allow only the three numbers.
- With CSS you hide the number icons. See Demo

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pzg2w24u/1/)

HTML

```
<input type="number" class="input first" id="first"  placeholder="000" min="1" max="999">
```

CSS

```
 input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
    input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
        /* display: none; <- Crashes Chrome on hover */
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        margin: 0; /* <-- Apparently some margin are still there even though it's hidden */
    }
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("first").oninput = function () {
    if (this.value.length > 3)
        this.value = this.value.slice(0,3); 
};

document.getElementById("first").onkeypress = function (evnt) {
return AllowNumber(evnt);
};

function AllowNumber(evnt) {
    var charCode = (evnt.which) ? evnt.which : evnt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && charCode != 46)
        return false;
    return true;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Best Solution is to use javascript

`function AllowNumber(evnt)
            {
                //alert("hf");
                var charCode = (evnt.which) ? evnt.which : evnt.keyCode;
                if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && charCode != 46)
                return false;
                return true;
            }`

Call above function on keypress!!